# Make custom view height match constraints in ConstraintLayout

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-custom-view, android-constraintlayout

I'm building a simple custom view, it's just a basic rectangular container at the moment cause I'm having some issues with the ConstraintLayout.

[The main layout setup. The textView is constrained to the parent while the Wire view is constrained to the parent and the top to the bottom of the textView](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdVtf.png)

In the onMeasure method I'm trying to make my view's height to match vertical constraint. What I mean is that I want my view's height to fill the space between the two vertical constraints.
Can't find any code about it online, anyone knows how to do it?

Comment: Hello, can you put some code from your view to show how it's implemented?

Comment: Its onMeasure method is still empty since i don't know how to make my custom view's height match the constraints.

Comment: Set its height to 0 using `ConstraintParams` and parent will make it fill the constraints.

Answer (score 1):

In order to match a constraint you need to set the width/height in zero, this way the view will take the space that the constraint declares for example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mytv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="text view"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:text="Your wire view"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/mytv" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Look at the "wire" view i set the height and 0 and then it takes all the space defined by their constraints.

[image: Layout example]

Comment: The problems is that "wire" is a custom view, so i have to inplement this behaviour by myself.

Comment: This is not true. You can leave measuring to the Android framework if you want.

Comment: You dont have to implemenet anything yourself to achieve what you want, just leave the custom view with wrap content and let the parent ConstraintLayout to do his job

Answer (score 0):

This is in addition to Nestor Perez's solution above but I will concentrate on the Kotlin code for `onMeasure()` for resolving the height and width.

First we declare **width** and **height** variables and set them to 0.

```
     class CustomRectangle @JvmOverloads constructor(context: Context,
                                                      attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
                                                      defStyleAttr: Int = 0) : View(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {
    
        //width and height variables
        private var widthSize = 0
        private var heightSize = 0 

//PAINT OBJECT
    private val paint = Paint().apply {

        style = Paint.Style.FILL
        
    }
......}
```

Inside on measure we use **resolveSizeAndState()** method to calculate the 2 dimens. We then set the height and width as shown below.

```
//ON_MEASURE
    override fun onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec: Int, heightMeasureSpec: Int) {
        val minWidth: Int = paddingLeft + paddingRight + suggestedMinimumWidth
        val w: Int = resolveSizeAndState(minWidth, widthMeasureSpec, 1)
        val h: Int = resolveSizeAndState(MeasureSpec.getSize(w), heightMeasureSpec, 0)
        widthSize = w
        heightSize = h
        setMeasuredDimension(w, h)
    }
```

Then `onDraw()` we draw the Custom Rectangle using the resolved **height** and **width**.

```
override fun onDraw(canvas: Canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas)

paint.color = Color.Whatever_Color
canvas.drawRect(0f, 0f, widthSize.toFloat(), heightSize.toFloat(), paint)
       

    }
```

Then as Nestor Perez has explained above we set the width and height to 0dp.

```
<com.custombutton
        android:id="@+id/custom_button"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp" ..../>
```

Cheers